# JavaCL/OpenCL segmentation fault in clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo

Tags: java, java-native-interface, segmentation-fault, opencl

For a research project, I am building a piece of software that is able to distribute the execution of a kernel onto different OpenCL devices using work size offsets. I am using JavaCL. For some reason, the same segmentation fault keeps coming up:

```
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libc++abi.dylib+0x25a13]  __dynamic_cast+0x29
C  [OpenCL+0x1c775]  clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo+0x9e1
C  [OpenCL+0x1ca64]  clEnqueueNDRangeKernel+0x65
C  [libbridj.dylib+0xd882]  dcCall_x64_sysv+0x61

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.nativelibs4java.opencl.library.OpenCLLibrary.clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(JJIJJJIJJ)I+0
...
```

I am testing three kernels: *Mandelbrot set*, *matrix multiplication*, and *Conway's game of life*. Weirdly, everything works fine for the Mandelbrot kernel. The other work sometimes, sometimes I get the segfault (with the same input configuration). The only difference between them (that I can think of) is that the Mandelbrot set is not operating on an input buffer, the other kernels are. I'm not sure if that could have any effect on the issue. What could cause this strange error?

- In all cases, the local work size parameter is null (Setting a value doesn't help).
- All kernels work correctly using only one device and no offsets

I'm working on a MacBook Pro, i7 2.6GHz, OSX 10.9.4. Devices I am using:

```
Device: HD Graphics 4000
Hardware version: OpenCL 1.2 
Driver version: 1.2(Jun  9 2014 13:24:09)
OpenCL version: OpenCL C 1.2 
Compute units: 16
Clock frequency: 1200
Maximum work item sizes: 512, 512, 512

Device: GeForce GT 650M
Hardware version: OpenCL 1.2 
Driver version: 8.26.26 310.40.45f01
OpenCL version: OpenCL C 1.2 
Compute units: 2
Clock frequency: 900
Maximum work item sizes: 1024, 1024, 64
```

The source code:

```
val globalWorkSizes =  Array(length.x, length.y)
val localWorkSizes:Array[Long] = null
val worksizeOffset = Array(offset.x, offset.y)
val result = clQueue.synchronized {
  val event = kernel.enqueueNDRange(clQueue, worksizeOffset, globalWorkSizes, localWorkSizes)
  val resultPointer = outBuffer.map(clQueue, CLMem.MapFlags.Read, offset, length, event)
  clQueue.flush()
  val floats = resultPointer.getFloats
  resultPointer.release()
  outBuffer.release()
  floats
}
```

Comment: Which of the two devices generates this error?  What version of JavaCL are you using?

Comment: I'm using JavaCL 1.0.0-RC3. I just did some isolated tests and the problem appears on both devices.

Comment: That version is very old.  Please try the latest version available at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/com/nativelibs4java/javacl/1.0-SNAPSHOT/javacl-1.0-20140629.155754-80-shaded.jar.

Comment: I've already tried a newer version (1.0-SNAPSHOT) from the maven repository - same result. I just tried the jar from your link, the segfault doesn't go away ...

Comment: Can you post the source code?

Comment: I edited the question and added the source code. Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using JavaCL in Scala.

Comment: @chippies your link to the latest version no longer works; could you post a new one?  According to https://code.google.com/p/javacl/wiki/Usage#With_Maven 1.0.0-RC3 seems to be the latest version.

Comment: @Ryan the Google Project Hosting page for JavaCL doesn't get updated much it seems.  The storage location for the newest version is always [https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/com/nativelibs4java/javacl/1.0-SNAPSHOT/](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/com/nativelibs4java/javacl/1.0-SNAPSHOT/).  The specific file to look for is javacl-*-shaded.jar, where * refers to all the version number information.  You can also get the source code and javadoc .jar files at the same location.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I looked at an open source OpenCL implementation (pocl) to find out what might be causing the segfault. It turns out that "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel" calls "clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo" like this:

```
size_t preferred_wg_multiple;
  cl_int retval = 
    POname(clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo)
    (kernel, command_queue->device, 
     CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE, 
     sizeof (size_t), &preferred_wg_multiple, NULL);
```

This being the only clue I had, I called JavaCL's "getPreferredWorkGroupSizeMultiple" on my kernel just before I enqueue it to read the value and maybe see what's going on:

```
val multiple = kernel.getPreferredWorkGroupSizeMultiple()(device)
Logger.debug("Multiple: " + multiple)
val event = kernel.enqueueNDRange(clQueue, worksizeOffset, globalWorkSizes, localWorkSizes)
```

Strangely, it seems that just calling this function eliminates the problem. I'm not sure if this counts as an answer to the question, but it fixes the problem. If anyone can think of a reasonable explenation, I would be grateful to hear it.